# Android app request permission before installation

Tags: java, android, kotlin

how to request permission before installation, there is a APK when i click, it will guide to installation page, and there is message :

"Do you want to install this application? it will get access to: --list of required permission---"

Comment: Does that happen to only one APK or all APKs?? In what Android Version are you installing?

Comment: That is not how permissions work on Android 6.0+. You can set a `targetSdkVersion` below 23 to get your desired effect, but you will not be allowed to ship your app on the Play Store (if that is how you planned on distributing it).

Comment: @CommonsWare Android Version 8.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Since android marshmallow, is implemented to require the permissions at runtime, rather than at the installation. You can check this link: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/usage-notes  and this explaining video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZqDdvhTZj0

Comment: but i try that APK on Android 8.1.0

Comment: as mentioned by CommonsWare, marshmallow is 6.0. This feature is available even since, including 8.1.0. Putting targetSdkVersion below 23 ( https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers this means before marshmallow ) will ask permissions before installation.